# OnNegotiationNeeded event in webrtc.PeerConnection not found (pion golang). But in official docs it show that it's there

Tags: go, webrtc, rtcpeerconnection, peer-connection, pion-net

[image: Screenshot from my PC after I tried to list out available methods in webrtc.PeerConnection object]ur.com/3Nydn.png

The official docs [pion webrtc doc](https://pkg.go.dev/github.com/pion/webrtc/v3?tab=doc#PeerConnection.OnNegotiationNeeded) shows that ***func (*PeerConnection) OnNegotiationNeeded*** exists. But actually this event is not present in the PeerConnection object. It can be checked from the given screenshot. Also other events are present except this one. What is the solution?

Answer (score 0):

I think we talked about this on [Slack](https://pion.ly/slack) and I think you solved it?

But for anyone else who hits this, `OnNegotationNeeded` only exists in `/v3` which is still in beta. If you want to use this make sure you aren't importing `/v2`.